# How can a module define a static property that is not shared between different classes that include it?

Tags: ruby, module

If I define a module like this:

```
module M
   @@p = []

   def self.included( base )
      def base.add( a )
          @@p += a
      end
   end

   def show_p
       @@p
   end
end
```

then every class that includes the module will have the same @@p array:

```
class A
   include M
end
class B
   include M
end

A.add "a"
B.add "b"

B.new.show_p

?> ["a", "b"]
```

Is it possible to define a unique static property for each individual class that includes the module, so the classes don't interfere with each other? i.e. so I can do this:

```
A.add "a"
B.add "b"

A.new.show_p

?> "a"

B.new.show_p

?> "b"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a static property, define a property on the class object itself:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.instance_variable_set(:@p, [])
    class << base
      attr_reader :p
      def add(a)
        @p << a
      end
    end
  end
end

class First
  include Foo
end

class Second
  include Foo
end

require 'pp'
First.add "a"
Second.add "b"
pp First.p
pp Second.p
```

Output:

```
["a"]
["b"]
```

Comment: Thanks. `instance_variable_set' is what I was looking for.

Comment: But, how can I access it from instances?

     f = First.new;
     f.class.p;

This kind of works. But won't work if I ever extended First.

Comment: @Peter For example, x.class.p.

Comment: @Peter Oh, I see. Do you want the class inherited from First to include the module automatically? (In either case, there is a solution but I still think you're doing something strange.)

Comment: I am extending ApplicationController and I need to be able to call the static methods from there and also each controller that extends it. It technically shouldn't be a problem that they share the same array, but occasionally I see remnants from the previous request, when navigating between views that use different controllers. I don't think this side-effect should be happening - not sure why it would - but it feels a bit messy that the possibility could arise in the first place.

Comment: @Peter Can you just clear the array in a before_filter? And are you sure the methods need to be static? (There is only one instance of each controller per request, as far as I understand.)

Comment: The array must be static, because it needs to be accessible from a static function.

Comment: It is static to avoid having to put this stuff in the constructor. It seems cleaner and more ror-esque to define meta information in a declarative style using static method calls in the class definition. But, I see there are limitations with inheritance of statics, and it's going to get messy to keep going down this track. Thanks for your help anyway.